# What is the correct way of injecting the bus if using owinselfhost?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nservicebus, owin, self-hosting

I have an asp.net web api controller that sends a nservicebus message i.e. Bus.Send(). this api controller is owin self hosted using owinselfhost packages.

what is the correct way of injecting the bus if im using owinselfhost?

--edit--

here's the code.. im using autofac now.. having these still gives me a null ref exception on the bus...

references:

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/containers/

--edit--

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        //this two controllers are from two separate class libraries.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(Test1Controller).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(Test2Controller).Assembly);

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        Configure.With()
            .UsingContainer<AutofacObjectBuilder>()
            .UnicastBus()
            .SendOnly();

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

Comment: What container are you using? I did this with Autofac without any issue, using Autofac module for Owin and WebAPI it was no problem at all.

Comment: u able to share how this is done using autofac? TIA

Comment: Create a container, do all registrations for your web framework according to the features you use and Autofac documentation, then use Autofac container with NServiceBus as described in the documentation. I don't know what you use, Owin is just a layer between web server and web framework and I have no idea what web framework you use, the registrations are framework specific.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev see modified question above..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked NServiceBus to use Autofac but you do not give it your container. If you pass your container there, you will get the bus injected to your controllers.

```
Configure.With()
        .UsingContainer<AutofacObjectBuilder>(container)
        .UnicastBus()
        .SendOnly();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.. i did that earlier and did not worked.. i was on nsb 4.6.1 and figured out to update to 4.7.5.. after the bits update all is working for me now.. thanks again for helping..